# ionic 3 App restarts rather than resumes

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have created ionic App with two pages , from Page1 if i navigate to Page2  .On press of hardware back button navigates back to Page1   , and again hardware back the app goes to background . If the App is opened from background the splash screen is reloaded and the app relaunches .

How to stop relaunching the app ?

Comment: its common behaviour in android that ! back button actually diminishes the navigation stack of the apps! and when it reaches at the last item of the stack and on back presses it kills the instance of the application! and on again call it gets RESTARTED!  .....    

I don't see the question here clearly! 
@namrata. are you willing to ask how to change the nature of on BackPress button so you could get the same thing done if you minimise an app with HOME button?   

as minimising from home button keeps apps instance alive and it resumes! and back button kills the instance and restarts

Comment: @Rizwanatta , yes i want change the nature of BackPress button to get the same behavior as minimize an app with HOME button.  On HardwareBack i donot want to kill the instance of the application.  As if i resume the app the splashscreen also reloads again

Comment: check my answer and lemme know in the comments if that helps ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-minimize/ to minimize the app

In app.component.ts

import { AppMinimize } from '@ionic-native/app-minimize';
import { App, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(platform: Platform,public appMinimize: AppMinimize, public app: App){
      platform.ready().then(() => {
          platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {

```
        let nav = app.getActiveNavs()[0];
        let activeView = nav.getActive();

            if (activeView.name === "Page1") {
                /** minimize the app in background **/
                this.appMinimize.minimize();
            }
            else {
                nav.pop();
        }

      });
  });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can show alert to confirm exit app. Modify your **app.component.ts** file in following way,

```
  import { Platform, IonicApp } from 'ionic-angular';

  constructor(public platform: Platform, private ionicApp: IonicApp){}

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      //back button handle
      this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
          if (this.navctrl.canGoBack()) {
            this.navctrl.pop();
          } else {
            this.showAlert();
          }
      });
    });
  }

  showAlert() {
    let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Exit Application?',
      message: 'Do you want to exit this application?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'No',
          handler: () => {}
        },
        {
          text: 'Yes',
          handler: () => {
            navigator['app'].exitApp();
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    confirm.present();
  }
```

Or you can simply press Home button instead of back button. So it will not relaunch your app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , actually my issue is if i am on homepage ,click on android hardware back ,the app closes (Expected behavior). But from the background if i try to click the app again , the App relaunches with splash screen .This is not expected behavior what can i do to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

Well as you explained yourself in comments maybe this would help a little ok?

follow this steps please :

**STEP ONE:**  REGISTER A FUNCTION AS ON BACK PRESS in your page where you want the action to be done of CUSTOM ON PAUSES!

**STEP TWO:** in that custom method REGISTER A SUBSCRIBER AND CALL THE ON PAUSE LISTENER ON and it you can have your function done in that

let's suppose you have two field vars for saving the subscriber events
like

```
sub1$:any
sub2$:any
```

in the constructor you can do something like this!

```
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {


          this.sub1$=this.platform.pause.subscribe(() => {        
              console.log('****YOURPAGE PAUSED****');
            this.appMinimize.minimize();
          }); 
        });

  });
```

NOTE!! ON PAUSE EVENT CAN BE CALLED MULTIPLE TIMES SO YOU SHOULD UNSUBSCRIBE TOO! while leaving out of the page like this

```
ionViewWillUnload() {
    this.sub1$.unsubscribe();
    this.sub2$.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Riwan atta , But i was getting error :: this.platform.pause()

Comment: @namratasalaskar please up vote my answer as it helped a little maybe! thnx for the edit though ^_^

Answer (score 0):

This thread is a few months old, but let me add this solution as well.

In your **app.module.ts**, add (or modify) this to your imports:

```js
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, { navExitApp: false}),
```

This will prevent your app from being closed when you are in the root page of your navigation stack.

Note however, that if you want to push the app to the background, you will still have to handle that in another way.
This solution only *prevents* your app from being closed.